# Counting program counting the new lines as characters

Tags: c, counting

I am learning C with The C Programming Language, however, there is a problem in a program that counts characters which is that it counts the new lines as characters.
How do I make my program not count the \n?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 1st version */
int main()
{
    int nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF){
        ++nc;
    }
    printf("%d\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: That depends on your definition of character. Technically, newline is a character, so, technically, your program isn't doing anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    int nc;
    int c;
    nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c != '\n' && c != '\r') ++nc;
    }
    printf("%d\n", nc);
}
```

in windows both '\r' and '\n' are used for the new line.

Comment: Not my downvote since I've run out of downvotes, but you cannot get `\r` from a text stream in Windows. If you did, the sequence would be `\r\n`.

Comment: Does it change anything in the code.

Comment: @P__J__ it doesn't change anything in the code, but it misleads readers that want to solve similar problems which may require to know the correct sequence CRLF `\r\n`.

Comment: @ChristianHujer did you DV me?

Comment: @P__J__ No I didn't. This was downvoted before I saw it for the first time.